# Request body undefined in supertest

Tags: node.js, express, chai, supertest

I am testing an express API with supertest. I am trying to pass in body parameters into the test, as can be seen in the code snippets below, but it appears that the body parameters don't get passed in correctly since I get an error message that the body parameters are undefined.

Running the test with command `mocha --recursive` returns the following error:

> Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

---

**Below is the code from file email-suite.js referencing supertest**

```js
'use strict';
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var supertest = require("supertest");
var chai = require("chai");
var should = chai.should();

var api = require("../server.js");

describe("Email Module", function() {
    this.timeout(25000);

    before(function(done){
        mongoose.createConnection(/* connectionstring */);

        mongoose.connection.on('open', function(err) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            console.log('connected to server');
        });

        done();
    });

    it("Check Email Count", function(done) {
        var body = { email: "email@email.com" };

        supertest(api)
            .post("/emailCount")
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .send(body)  // body is undefined
            .expect(200)
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if(err) return done(err);
                res.body.count.should.equal(2);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

---

**Below is the code from file email-api.js**

```js
'use strict';
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.post('/emailCount', function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email; // req.body is undefined
}

module.exports = router;
```

---

**Below is the code from the file server.js**

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);

var router = require("./user/email-api");

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(app.get("port"), function() {
    console.log("App started on port " + app.get("port"));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put `body-parser` always after `express object` and before every routes  in main server file like this

```
 var app = express();
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

//Router task start from here

Other wise always will get `undefined` since router call first and body parsed later.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: This did not solve the problem for me. Still getting "undefined" values for any request body object, in each field

Comment: i just had this exact problem, spent hours debugging, couldnt figure out what the hell was wrong. it was just order of body parser and routes. i cant believe this. thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [abdulbarik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3260137/abdulbarik) for your answer. I want to add some extra information to aid clarity in case people are still getting `undefined` values for the request body object, and if (as in my case) your routers and tests are setup differently.

Here is the router that we shall test:

```
// router.js

const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ success: true, data: req.body });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The following test code will result in the request body being `undefined`, and thus the test failing:

```
// router.test.js

const express = require("express");
const request = require("supertest");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// set up the test app - this will fail
const app = express();
app.use("/routerPath", require("./router")); // this will cause the test to fail, as the router should be setup after the body-paser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// run the test
it("successful response", async () => {
  const response = await request(app)
    .post("/routerPath")
    .send({
      firstname: "John",
      lastname: "Smith",
    })
    .set("Accept", "application/json");

  expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
  expect(response.body).toEqual({
    success: true,
    data: {
      firstname: "John",
      lastname: "Smith",
    },
  });
});
```

The reason why, as explained by [abdulbarik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3260137/abdulbarik), is that the `body-parser` code should always be before the router code, so that the parser runs before the router. To make the test pass, simply swap these lines around:

```
// set up the test app - this will work now
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/routerPath", require("./router")); // the router setup should happen after the body-parse setup
```

I hope that is a helpful clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 bodyparser is deprecated, and is now included in express. The following solution worked for me :

`app.use(express.json());`

Make sure you call this before initializing your routes.

**Note:** If you are using `4.16.0` or later express version.